# Is there anyway easy way to setup Postgres for the Ubuntu DigitalOcean 1click-install?

Tags: web, vps, digital-ocean

Is there anyway to setup the 1-click installer at digital ocean to use postgres instead of mysql for the ubuntu/nginx/unicorn setup?

Comment: Try Database Labs -- it's a one-click Postgres as a service on DigitalOcean: https://www.databaselabs.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You have to replace the MySQL with PostgreSQL manually.

The one-click Digital Ocean install doesn't really do anything with the database other than install the MySQL software on the server and set up a default user. I think it creates a test.db, that isn't connected to any app or anything. It's just there.

To change over to PostgreSQL uninstall mySQL and install PostgreSQL. Plus, if you're setting up your own VPS you have to jump in and get practice with this sort of thing.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.0 (whichever ver is installed)
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

If you aren't alerady using it, I recommend to install pgadmin3 to work with a PostgreSQL db. It's a good tool: http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/